# Aws Elasticsearch: How to change mapping type of location { lat: float, lon: float} to geo_point

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, elasticsearch

### **Can anyone guide me to change the mapping type of location to geo_point.?**

Service: Aws ElasticSearch (6.2 Version)
Database: dynamodb

I am using aws elastic search service to filter values based on my location.
As per the documentation i have created a trigger lambda function dbtoEs which is a python code soon after the record is added its indexed.

Since my location type in dynamodb is 
    type Location {
           lat: Float
           lon: Float
    }

When i go to Aws ElasticSearch and check in indices the mapping type for this field is also 
      location {
           lat float
           lon float
      }

As per the Elastic geo distance query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) the mapping type of location should be **geo_point**

**Example of search query filter**

```
    filter:[ 
        { 
          geo_distance:{ 
             distance:"2000 km",
             location:{ 
                  lon:77.676,
                  lat:12.998
              },
           }
        },
      { 
        range:{ 
            createdAt:{ 
            gte:"now-1d/d"
           }
         }
        }
       ],
```

**Search Response**

```
 { 
   "took":4,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{ 
      "total":5,
      "successful":4,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":1,
      "failures":[ 
         { 
            "shard":4,
            "index":"spot",
            "node":"*******",
            "reason":{ 
               "type":"query_shard_exception",
               "reason":"failed to find geo_point field 
                         [location]",
               "index_uuid":"**********",
               "index":"***"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "hits":{ 
      "total":0,
      "max_score":null,
      "hits":[ 

      ]
   }
}


**Result Required: Filtered results should be based on location**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem

*Help: Initially I faced difficulty how to change the type alone, when I implemented elastic search with dynamodb it creates index automatically as soon a record is added in dynamo DB, We cannot change the type of location in dynamo DB as it doesn't support. We have to change type in Elasticsearch index so follow the steps below*

1) Change Elastic Search mapping type manually using kibana UI.
By default, the mapping type will be the same as the column data type we have to change the type of location to geo_point.

2) GET /xyz/_mappings
It returns all the mappings with types
Copy the mappings

3) DELETE XYZ/
Delete the mappings

4) PUT XYZ/
Change the mapping type of location to geo_point in the copied mappings and 
create mappings using 
PUT XYZ
{ mappings: ... }

***Happy Day***

Answer (score 0):

You need to create mapping before first record is indexed. In absence of mapping elasticsearch interprets the type dynamically. In this case it is float.

Look for mapping api for elasticsearch and create mapping for geo_point field using lat longs.